# Creating multiple if else array_key_exists condition on Drupal 8

Tags: php, drupal-8

I'm trying to figure out how I can create multiple if else array_key_exists conditions. They have different purpose. The first condition adds a redirection to a internal page while the second provides redirection to a external page. The Second condition checks if the value inside the array matches with the condition it will redirect to a external page.

```
$shortCodes = [
    "/careers-aim"                   => 'careers-aim/faculty-postings',
    // need to fix this part
    "/node/15"                       => 'careers-aim/faculty-postings',
    "/alumni"                        => 'alumni/triple-a',
    "/scholarship-and-financial-aid" => "admissions/scholarship-and-financial-aid",
    "/asianforum"                    => "http://asianforum2018.com/",
];


$urlPath = Drupal::service('path.current')->getPath();
if (array_key_exists($urlPath, $shortCodes)) {
    _redirect(base_path() . $shortCodes[$urlPath]);
}

if (array_key_exists($urlPath, $shortCodes == "/asianforum")) {
    _redirect("http://asianforum2018.com/");
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since a fully qualified url will begin with http...

```
if (array_key_exists($urlPath, $shortCodes)){
    if (substr($shortCodes[$urlPath], 0, 3) === "http"){
            _redirect($shortCodes[$urlPath]);
        } else {
            _redirect(base_path() . $shortCodes[$urlPath]);
        }
}
```

Comment: Sorry for my ignorance what does this line of code do  `if (substr($shortCodes[$urlPath], 0, 4 ) === "http")` especially the `0, 4`

Comment: No worries, it's just checking if $shortCodes[$urlPath] begins with "http".  http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php

Comment: Should be 0, 3 though.  My mistake.

Comment: If I understand it correctly the numbers `0, 3` is the range right

Comment: Sorry, would it be possible to check the value instead of using a `range 0,3`

Comment: What we're effectively doing is discovering a third piece of information hidden in `$shortCodes`.  It has the key, `"/careers-aim"`, a value `'careers-aim/faculty-postings'` and the third piece of information we need is metadata about the value; whether it's a fully qualified url or just a relative url.  We are inferring the answer to that question by inspecting the value.  Should a relative url ever begin with http?  Hopefully not.  You could make the check smarter by checking if the value begins with "http://", but then what if you want to refer to a https:// website? Does that help?

Comment: There are other string functions you could use instead of substr, but there is nothing like `strbeginswith()`.  One example of something else you could use is `strpos()`.  This is one of those situations where you sort of just have to know all of the string functions, or read through the list and find one that's suitable to your needs. http://php.net/manual/en/ref.strings.php